# Unable to automatically source custom Vim files

Tags: bash, zsh, vim

Here is a repo with my exact set-up: https://github.com/Integralist/Fresh-Install/tree/master/Shell

Here is the link specifically to my `.vimrc` file: https://github.com/Integralist/Fresh-Install/blob/master/Shell/.vimrc

Here is the link specifically to my custom `.vim` files: https://github.com/Integralist/Fresh-Install/tree/master/Shell/vim

---

I'm trying to automatically source some custom `.vim` files.

For automation to work I realised I needed my custom `.vim` files to be in a specific order and so I had to prefix the file names with a numerical number. For example, `1.settings.vim`

I tried putting them inside of `.vim/plugin` but when I open Vim none of my plugins are running so I have to manually execute `:BundleInstall` (or before starting Vim run `vim +BundleInstall`) but the moment I close Vim and start it again the plugins again are not running. So unless there is a way to get Vim to automatically execute the bundle install command (and only do it once, because doing it every time I open Vim is just ridiculous).

So instead, I decided to try and automatically source them myself via Vim Script.

The following script works...

```
set runtimepath+=$DROPBOX/Fresh\ Install/Shell/vim
runtime 1.settings.vim
runtime 2.vundle.vim
runtime 3.mapping.vim
runtime 4.commands.vim
```

...but isn't scalable because every time I add a new `.vim` file then I'll have to update the script.

So I tried another way...

Note: my `.zshrc` exports the variable `DROPBOX` and sets it to my Dropbox path.

If I open up Vim in a new tab (so I'm in my `~/` directory) and execute `:echo $DROPBOX` I see `/Users/markmcdonnell/Dropbox`.

If I open up Vim in a new tab (so I'm in my `~/` directory) and execute `:echo isdirectory("$DROPBOX/")` I get back `0` which means Vim cannot locate that directory.

But if I open up Vim in a new tab (so I'm in my `~/` directory) and execute `:echo isdirectory("/Users/markmcdonnell/Dropbox/")` (which is the same as what `:echo $DROPBOX` returned with the addition of an extra forward slash at the end) I get back a `1` which means Vim *CAN* locate that directory.

So there is something not quite right with how Vim Script interprets a manually typed path and one that is expanded from an environment variable.

An example script I tried was...

```
if isdirectory("$DROPBOX/Fresh Install/Shell/vim")
  for file in split(globpath('$DROPBOX/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/', '*.vim'), '\n')
    execute 'source ' file
  endfor
endif
```

...but the files weren't being sourced and that's when I realised that within Vim the line `isdirectory("$DROPBOX/Fresh Install/Shell/vim")` was returning `0`.

I can't manually enter the full path because I sync my files across different machines and so the path changes.

So instead I modified the if statement to: `isdirectory(expand('%:p:h').'/vim')` which returns `1` when run within Vim (this is when I `cd` into the Dropbox folder `/Fresh Install/` and open the `/Shell/.vimrc` file).

So, `:echo expand('%:p:h')` returns `/Users/markmcdonnell/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell` hence it has managed to locate the correct directory.

But again this did not work.

I also tried another format (but essentially the same process just more concisely written): `"   execute join(map(split(glob("$DROPBOX/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/*.vim"), "\n"), '"source " . v:val'), "\n")`

Again did not work.

I then tried...

```
for file in split(globpath('$DROPBOX/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/', '*.vim'), '\n')
  execute 'source ' . file
endfor
```

...but without checking the folder existed (because it should always exist).

But now I get the error: `Only one file name allowed: source /Users/markmcdonnell/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/1.settings.vim`

So it looks like it's almost working but maybe the space in the path is causing the script to think there are two arguments when it's really just one.

I went back to the previous (non concise version) and tried to quote the command:

`execute 'source ' . "file"` and `execute 'source ' . "$file"` and also `execute "source $file"`

But again, none of these worked.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but any help appreciated.

### UPDATE:

```
let files = split(glob("$DROPBOX/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/*.vim"), "\n")
let mapped = map(files, '"source " . v:val')
execute join(mapped, "\n")
```

This is the same command as before but expanded a little bit.

I think I need to be able to get a set of double quotes around the `v:val` so that when the command is `execute`d then the space in the file name wont cause an issue.

### UPDATE 2:

Here is the result of running `:verbose set rtp?`

```
runtimepath=
~/.vim/bundle/vundle
~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
~/.vim/bundle/tomorrow-night-vim
~/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown
~/.vim/bund le/vim-cucumber
~/.vim/bundle/vim-misc
~/.vim/bundle/tagbar
~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
~/.vim/bundle/vim-repeat
~/.vim/bundle/vim -commentary
~/.vim/bundle/ack.vim
~/.vim/bundle/vim-endwise
~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline
~/.vim/bundle/tmuxline.vim
~/.vim/bundle/web api-vim
~/.vim/bundle/Gist.vim
~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive
~/.vim/bundle/emmet-vim
~/.vim/bundle/rename.vim
~/.vim/bundle/vim-gitgu tter
~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
~/.vim/bundle/vim-haml
~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround
~/.vim/bundle/html5.vim
~/.vim/bundle/tabular
~/.vim /bundle/camelcasemotion
~/.vim
/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles
/usr/local/share/vim/vim74
/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles/after
~/.vim /after
~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim
~/.vim/bundle/vundle/after
~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/after
~/.vim/bundle/tomorrow-night-vim
/after
~/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/after
~/.vim/bundle/vim-cucumber/after
~/.vim/bundle/vim-misc/after
~/.vim/bundle/tagbar/after

Last set from ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim
```

This was the result after I removed the following snippet of code...

```
set runtimepath+=$DROPBOX/Fresh\ Install/Shell/vim
runtime 1.settings.vim
runtime 2.vundle.vim
runtime 3.mapping.vim
runtime 4.commands.vim
```

...which I'm using to manually source the vim files.

It's worth noting as well that I have a `BufOnly.vim` file within `~/.vim/plugin` that is being automatically loaded so why the other `.vim` files aren't is very odd

### UPDATE 3

Here is the result of running `:scriptnames`

```
1: ~/.vimrc
2: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/1.settings.vim
3: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
4: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
5: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
6: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
7: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/2.vundle.vim
8: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
9: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle.vim
10: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle/config.vim
11: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/tomorrow-night-vim/colors/tomorrow-night-bright.vim
12: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/ftdetect/markdown.vim
13: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-cucumber/ftdetect/cucumber.vim
14: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-haml/ftdetect/haml.vim
15: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
16: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/indent.vim
17: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/3.mapping.vim
18: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/4.commands.vim
19: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/plugin/ctrlp.vim
20: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
21: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/tagbar/plugin/tagbar.vim
22: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/plugin/youcompleteme.vim
23: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-commentary/plugin/commentary.vim
24: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/ack.vim/plugin/ack.vim
25: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-endwise/plugin/endwise.vim
26: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/plugin/airline.vim
27: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
28: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/tmuxline.vim/plugin/tmuxline.vim
29: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/Gist.vim/plugin/gist.vim
30: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim
31: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/emmet-vim/plugin/emmet.vim
32: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/rename.vim/plugin/rename.vim
33: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim
34: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
35: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
36: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
37: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
38: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_item.vim
39: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
40: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim
41: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_file_node.vim
42: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim
43: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
44: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim
45: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
46: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
47: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim
48: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/tabular/plugin/Tabular.vim
49: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/camelcasemotion/plugin/camelcasemotion.vim
50: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/plugin/1.settings.vim
51: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
52: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/init.vim
53: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/parts.vim
54: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
55: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
56: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/ctrlp.vim
57: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/hunks.vim
58: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/tagbar.vim
59: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/branch.vim
60: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
61: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
62: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
63: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/tomorrow.vim
64: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
65: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
66: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/util.vim
67: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
68: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/plugin/2.vundle.vim
69: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/plugin/3.mapping.vim
70: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/plugin/4.commands.vim
71: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/plugin/BufOnly.vim
72: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
73: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
74: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
75: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
76: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
77: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
78: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
79: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
80: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
81: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
82: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/tabular/after/plugin/TabularMaps.vim
83: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/tabular/autoload/tabular.vim
84: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
85: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/tagbar/autoload/tagbar.vim
86: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/scripts.vim
87: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/syntax/nerdtree.vim
88: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim/autoload/ctrlp/utils.vim
89: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim
90: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/indent/vim.vim
91: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vim.vim
92: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/perl.vim
93: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/pod.vim
94: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/ruby.vim
95: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim
```

Again, as per UPDATE 2 this is without any of the code I had in my `.vimrc` file before that was manually sourcing my separate vim script files. The only code in my `.vimrc` at the point of running `:scriptnames` was...

```
if filereadable(".vimlocal")
  source .vimlocal
endif
```

...but interestingly you can see above that the files within `~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/` look to be loading (that's if that is what `:scriptnames` is showing?). Note that the files within `~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/vim/` are a copy of the files within `~/.vim/plugin`

Comment: Have you tried putting a \ before the space and seeing if it works then?

Comment: your modularized vim config file looks neat, however I am afraid that it could be inconvenient for daily usage and config tuning. vimrc usually won't more than 1000 lines, most people won't reach 200 lines. putting them into 5+ files/modules makes a little complicated. If you want to have different profiles, you can create different vimrc files. my 2 cents

Comment: @bilalq yes I tried that and it didn't work. I've added an updated above.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `$FOO` points to a real existing directory…

```
:echo isdirectory("$FOO")
```

returns `0` because the string `$FOO` is used and you don't have a `$FOO` directory.

```
:echo isdirectory($FOO)
```

returns `1` because the value of `$FOO` is used instead of the string `$FOO`.

---

Might I add that I find your setup needlessly complex?

Answer (score 0):

I got about as far as

> I tried putting them inside of .vim/plugin but when I open Vim none of my plugins are running

I would rather fix a flat tire than reinvent the wheel.

By `.vim/plugin` do you mean `~/.vim/plugin/`, so that your files are

```
~/.vim/plugin/1.settings.vim
```

and so on?  If so, and if you are on a *NIX-like system, then this should work.  See `:help load-plugins` for the reasons vim might skip the step of loading plugin files.  Try `:verbose set rtp?` to see whether you should be using `~/.vim` or something else.  Use `:scriptnames` to make sure that they are *not* being loaded--there might be some other explanation for what you are seeing.

Update (based on your comments):

I did not expect `~/.vim/plugin` to be listed as part of `'rtp'`.  I did expect `~/.vim` to be listed, and it is.  According to `:help load-plugins`, the `plugin/` part of the path is added.

You say that `BufOnly.vim` is sourced from `~/.vim/plugin/`, but it is listed as `71: ~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/plugin/BufOnly.vim`.  Have you made a sym link from `~/.vim` to `~/Dropbox/Fresh Install/Shell/.vim/`?  The files you want, `1.settings.vim` through `4.commands.vim`, are in the same directory, and they are also sourced, according to your output from `:scriptnames` (Lines 50 and 68-70, right before `BufOnly.vim`).

I do not see anything mysterious here.  The files you want to be sourced *are* being sourced.  If they are not having the effect you wanted, then look elsewhere for the explanation.

By the way, there are about 17 files sourced between `1.settings.vim` and `2.vundle.vim`.  I am pretty sure that `1.settings.vim` must trigger these other files.

Comment: see my update 2 above which shows the content of the runtime path, the ~/.vim plugin folder isn't referenced at all.

Comment: Also worth noting that I have a `BufOnly.vim` inside ~/.vim/plugin and that script is run automatically so why the others aren't sourced automatically as well makes it even stranger

Comment: Added a note to UPDATE 2 to clarify what I was doing

Comment: there is now an UPDATE 3 with the `:scriptnames` results

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem. symbolic links are not recognises in ˜/.vim/plugin , so you will have to copy your files there, not create symbolic links towards the "git" folder that contains all your files.